# Editor/outliner with Newton-style handwriting input on iPod touch

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, ipod-touch, handwriting

Is there a text editor for the iPod Touch that fills the function of the visionary-but-before-its-time Notes application on the legendary [Apple Newton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_%28platform%29)? Specifically, looking for something that accepts typed OR handwritten text, freely sketched graphics, collapsable outline with check boxes, etc.?

In other words, is there software for our handheld devices in 2012 as sophisticated as the state of the art from 1996?

Comment: You would need a special pen to write on a touch display. Using fingers for handwriting is not really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [MyScript Memo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myscript-memo/id446368116?mt=8)

...fulfills a fraction of your requirement list:

- **handwriting recognition** for 30 languages
- convert handwriting to digital text or export as image
- create sketches

I cannot confirm whether this also supports keyboard input.

[image]

Comment: I still doubt the effectiveness of writing using the hand. Fingers are fat and require more space when writing. On the other hand a stylus does require some effort to write when you cannot rest your hands like one is used to. But a stylus is thin and precise. It does not cover your writing like your finger would.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com) the app du jour for this kind of thing?